# Nested attributes will not save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have searched stackoverflow thoroughly and tried every result that has come up but I am still stuck. Here is the problem.

I have an app that allows me to upload music files. Once the file is uploaded, I scan the ID3 data and use that data to populate all the various info for the object in my database....such as title, album, year, genre and so forth.

The artist field sometimes has many artists, so for this field I wrote a method that takes all the artists and hashes it as such;

```
{:artist => [{:name=>"Artist 1"},{:name=>"Artist 2"}]}
```

This data is now included in the object that I want to save to my database and looks as follows;

```
#<Track id: 76, name: nil, title: "song title", tpath: "file_name.mp3", created_at:      "2013-06-08 23:31:24", updated_at: "2013-06-08 23:31:24", track_number: 6, artist: {:artist   => [{:name=>"Artist 1"},{:name=>"Artist 2"}]}, album_artist: "Artist Name", year: 2012,   genre: "nil", bpm: nil, length: 252, size: 79872, user_id: 2>
```

In my tracks_controller(where all of the action is happening) I have this for my create action;

```
def create
@track = Track.new(params[:track])
@track.libraries << @library
@track.parse_id3(@track)
@track.update_attributes(@track[:artist]) --># I also tried @track.artist
respond_to do |format|
  if @track.save
    format.html { redirect_to library_track_path(@library, @track), notice: 'Track was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @library_track, status: :created, location: @track }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @track.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

**The problem is that active record is not saving/updating my Artists(in the Artist Table) with the data I am providing, but the track is successfully saved to my database without error.**

I have the following relationship setup between Artists and Tracks;

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :age, :birthdate, :first_name, :last_name, :name
    has_many :tracks, :through => :artist_tracks
    has_many :artist_tracks
end
```

Join Table looks like;

```
class ArtistTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :album_artist, :artist_id, :track_id
      belongs_to :artist
      belongs_to :track
end
```

And Track looks like;

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :title, :tpath, :track_number, :artist, :album_artist,
      :year, :genre, :bpm, :length, :size, :user_id, :artists_attrubutes      

      mount_uploader :tpath, TpathUploader

      belongs_to :user
      has_many :libraries, :through => :track_libraries
      has_many :track_libraries
      has_many :playlists, :through => :playlist_tracks
      has_many :playlist_tracks
      has_many :artists, :through => :artist_tracks
      has_many :artist_tracks

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists

end
```

The only form involved is the form with a single field asking for the location of the file to be uploaded.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

---

I got it to work, here is what was needed.

```
@track.update_attributes(:artists_attributes => @track.parse_id3(@track))
```

The **.parse_id3** is a method I wrote that scans all the artist in the MP3's artist field and turns them into;

```
:artists_attributes => [{:name=>"Artist 1"},{:name=>"Artist 2"}]}
```

I had tried;

```
@track.update_attributes(:artists_attributes)
```

Apparently I needed to add the **@track.parse_id3(@track)** piece for it to work.

Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the direction of your nesting is incorrect.  `Artist` could `accept_nested_attributes_for` `Track` because the `Track` `belongs_to` the `Artist`.  In your example you are trying to link a `Track` to an `Artist` that doesn't yet exist. I think you need to build the relationship the other way around for nested_attributes to work

Comment: That hash isn't what nested attributes is expecting. How are you constructing the form?

Comment: Oh, you're getting it from the id3 tags - i wouldn't use nested attributes here at all - just build the artist objects directly

Comment: What is nested attributes expecting? Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is a typo:

```
artists_attrubutes
```

besides, in your controller try to write:

```
@track = Track.new params[:track]
@track.save
```

to use this you should organize your parameters in your view.

Comment: The typo was from me fixing the code I copied in to the stackoverflow post, its actually correct in the model. I also tried what you suggested and it did not work. Thanks for the suggestion however.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, here is what was needed.

```
@track.update_attributes(:artists_attributes => @track.parse_id3(@track))
```

The **.parse_id3** is a method I wrote that scans all the artist in the MP3's artist field and turns them into;

```
:artists_attributes => [{:name=>"Artist 1"},{:name=>"Artist 2"}]}
```

I had tried;

```
@track.update_attributes(:artists_attributes)
```

Apparently I needed to add the **@track.parse_id3(@track)** piece for it to work.

Thanks for all the responses!